# How do I create this type of xml layout

Tags: android, tags, material-components, material-components-android, android-chips

[image]Please I need help on achieving this type of layout in android xml.

I have tried with `RecyclerView` and [this library](https://github.com/tommykw/TagView)  but I still did not get what I wanted.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: We cannot help you if you don't show us what you tried and didn't work. Please show us some code snippets.

Comment: I just need an idea on the best approach for this. I don't need a solution with code.

Comment: You should post what you tried with the RecyclerView and didn't work. This is the only way to help you. The RecyclerView approach sounds correct and you probably need a GridLayoutManager for it.

Comment: It is not clear which is the screen you are trying to achieve. Post a screen pls.

Comment: please review my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) and the [**`Chip`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Chip.md) component.

You can define it with a layout if it is static:

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
    android:id="@+id/chip_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- Chips can be declared here, or added dynamically. -->

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Entry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:chipIcon="@drawable/...."
        android:text="@string/..."/>

     .....

</com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

Or you can do it programmatically.
Define the layout for the single Chip (`chip_layout.xml`)

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

In your code:

```
ChipGroup reflowGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.chip_group);
for (.....) {
      Chip chip =
          (Chip) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.chip_layout, chipGroup, false);
      chip.setText(....);
      .....
      chipGroup.addView(chip);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `ChipGroup` in the android Material Design.

Please refer,

[Chips](https://www.material.io/develop/android/components/chip/) and [ChipGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/ChipGroup)

Comment: please review my question